# React Native component above WebView not rendering properly

Tags: android, react-native, webview, android-webview

I have a component that renders a WebView along with a Text component at the top and bottom of the screen:

```
return (
        <Container>
            <Text>TEXT TOP</Text>
            <WebView source={{uri: url}} />
            <Text>TEXT BOTTOM</Text>
        </Container>
);
```

The issue that I am facing is that the "TEXT TOP" does not appear the first time I navigate to the specific component, while the "TEXT BOTTOM" appears just fine. In order to make the top text appear, I need to do one of the following:

- Navigate to another component and come back
- Change the phone's orientation
- Interact with the WebView (scroll or press on an input field)

I have tried with both the WebView component from `'react-native'` and also from `'react-native-webview'` without managing to change the behaviour.

Comment: Can you post the style attributes you're using?

Comment: I am not using any style attributes as I have stripped down everything during debugging. My code is identical to the one I provided. Also I forgot to mention that this issue only appears when I run the app on a mobile device, but it never appeared on the Android emulator.

Comment: I have the same problem, do u solve it?

Comment: Did you manage you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Place all other content below the WebView and position using absolute.
I have been trying to resolve this issue for a while and found that this solution works like a charm!

```
        <WebView source={{uri: url}} style={{ marginTop: 60 }} />
        <Text style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, height: 60 }}>TEXT TOP</Text>
        <Text>TEXT BOTTOM</Text>
```

Comment: Exactly, This worked perfectly, after adding content below to WebView

Answer (score 1):

I have this example it renders both text on top and bottom along with webview in 
   middle.Hope it helps.Run this code on expo snack and view it on your device.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to
          get a shareable url.
        </Text>
        <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native' }} />
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to
          get a shareable url.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: what if I have html to render in webview

Comment: I know that but the problem is that I am not able to display the complete html data.

Comment: can you post your sample code so that i can help out?

Comment: yes here it is ` <MyWebView style = {{marginLeft:-10,width:window.width,justifyContent:'center' }}
                                source={{html: htmlResponse}}
                                       scalesPageToFit={true}
                                startInLoadingState={true}
                            />`

Comment: can you let me know the htmlResponse that you are trying to display

Comment: Actually, the problem is not with the htmlResponse. The problem is with the webview it is rendered first after that header is displayed. Firstly, the webview loads completely when I navigate to the screen and then the header containing text is not displayed until the webview is loaded completety. In debug it works fine but in release mode it is giving this bug.

Comment: Finally, I did resolve it on my own. I had to make use of react native webview in order to resolve that problem. Thanks for staying with me during the trouble. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  Any components above the WebView would not render and couldn't be forced to render until the WebView had finished loading.

I was able to work around this by having the WebView load a local html resource (source = require('xxx')).  Then implement the WebView's onLoadEnd to flip a component state variable to load the real URI you want to show.

It seems that the layout of the screen is delayed or otherwise impeded by the first load of the WebView.  I don't know if the first page being local causes the engine to compute the layout inline since it doesn't need to wait on an asynchronous fetch result.

Why the layout of the screen would need to change based on the contents of the WebView is unclear to me.  Perhaps it just looks like that's what's happening.